# Changing a newly appended element in JQuery

Tags: jquery

So when I check the original boxes off, they disappear. But when you switch lists and the new checkbox appears, when you check it it does not disappear. Why?

EDIT: I made changes to the code to reflect the answer. I am wondering now why the the textbox there by default deletes when pressing enter, but the new one that appears does not?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(document).on("click",".items",function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    
    $("li").click(function () {
        $("li").removeAttr("class");
        $(this).attr("class","selectedlist");
        $(".items").remove();
        $("#itemsbar").append('<div class=\"items\" id=\"c1div\"><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"c1\" name=\"c1\" /> \
        <label for=\"c1\"><span></span>New Box~</label></div>');
    });
    
    $("#itemsbar > p").click(function () {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#itemsbar").append('<input class=/"addnew/" type=/"text/"></input>');
    });
    
    $(document).on("keyup",'.addnew', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $(this).remove();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="listsbar">
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <ul id="lists">
            <li id="l1" class="selectedlist">Test List</a></li>
            <li id="l2">Test List 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="itemsbar">
        <div class="items" id="c1div"><input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="c1" />
        <label for="c1"><span></span>Check Box 1</label></div>
        <div class="items" id="c2div"><input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="c2" />
        <label for="c2"><span></span>Check Box 2</label></div>
        <p>Click to Add</p>
        <input class="addnew" type="text"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Binding issue it is. Rebind the event or do event delegation to a parent. Things will work.

Comment: I am binding it to the document itself right? So why isn't it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$(".items").click(function () {
```

to

```
 $(document).on("click",".items",function() {
```

You are binding on the document ready to the items that are on the document, so when you bring a new item on, it does not have this listener bound to it.

Comment: In my training I never saw something like that. So I am not sure I understand this concept at all. Now I feel I am missing a fundamental concept of JQuery.

Comment: @Paul the item you are appending to the page with the li click is not in the document to begin with. When you say  $(".items").click(function () { inside document ready - you are saying anything with the class of items gets bound with this click listener. The items you are apending are not there currently so they are not bound, so when you say  $(document).on("click",".items",function() { , you scan inside the document for anything with class of items to fire the event.

Comment: @Paul We are binding to the document instead of the .items themselves, so it doesn't matter if items come or go, it will always check inside of the document, and in your case your are binding to the elements that are there - so if they are not on the page when bound, or leave the page, they lose the bind.

Comment: I tried this same tactic to make a new textbox disappear on hitting the enter key. Not working again so maybe this is too complex?

Comment: I updated the code in my original post, thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Paul what exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: I am trying to make it so when you enter text into the box and press the enter key, the box dissapears.

Comment: Eventually the box will disappear, and the text entered will become a new item in the list.

Comment: @Paul keypress is a jquery thing, try keyup instead $(document).on("keyup", ".addnew", function (e) {

Comment: Nope, still won't work. Oddly enough in jsfiddle when I click "Click to Add" it does add a new text field. On here it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @paul make a fiddle an i can help you a lot more easily  :)

Comment: Okay, thanks that worked. What do you mean by escape the add new class?

Comment: @Paul you had an .append('<input class=/"addnew/" , there is no need for the slashes

Comment: Why not? I thought any quotes need to have the slashes so the software doesn't get confused?

Comment: @Paul nah there's no need when using append, only thing you really need to watch out for is escaped stuff and delimiter issues, if you try and append that it will literally put in class=/"addnew/" as apposed to class"addnew", hence why it was not working

Comment: @Paul please mark this as correct so it will close. I answered your original question and then some :).

Comment: Just figured out how to do that, thanks! New to the site